ReactI18nextProvider does not trigger re-render on language change with i18next and NextJs
I'm building a NextJs application using react-i18next and want to dynamically change the language based on the locale prop. I'm implementing a custom I18nextProvider to manage the i18n instance and provide it via context.
Here's my implementation:
'use client';

import {
  ReactNode, useEffect, useMemo, useState,
} from 'react';
import { i18n as i18nType, createInstance } from 'i18next';
import { I18nextProvider as ReactI18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import initTranslations from '@app/i18n';

let globalI18n: i18nType | null = null;

export const I18nextProvider = ({ children, locale }: { children: ReactNode; locale: string }) => {
  const i18n = useMemo(() => {
    if (!globalI18n) {
      globalI18n = createInstance();
      void initTranslations(locale, 'common', globalI18n);
    } else if (typeof window === 'undefined' && globalI18n.resolvedLanguage !== locale) {
      void globalI18n.changeLanguage(locale);
    }
    return globalI18n;
  }, [locale]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (globalI18n && globalI18n.resolvedLanguage !== locale) {
      void globalI18n.changeLanguage(locale);
    }
  }, [locale]);

  return <ReactI18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>{children}</ReactI18nextProvider>;
};

The Problem
Even though I call changeLanguage when the locale changes, the ReactI18nextProvider does not always trigger a re-render of the consuming components. The new language is loaded, but my UI components that use translations remain unchanged.
What I Tried
State with Key:
I used a providerKey state and attempted to increment it on locale change to force React to re-mount the ReactI18nextProvider.
useEffect(() => {
  if (globalI18n && globalI18n.resolvedLanguage !== locale) {
    void globalI18n.changeLanguage(locale).then(() => {
      setProviderKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);
    });
  }
}, [locale]);

return <ReactI18nextProvider key={providerKey} i18n={i18n}>{children}</ReactI18nextProvider>;

Any insights or suggestions on debugging this would be greatly appreciated.
